# React-redux state with external json

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-saga

I want to list posts in PostList.js component from JSON file
I use react-redux for state managment and redux-saga to get json file

My components are Post.js and PostList.js:

**Post.js**

```
    const Post = ({ post }) => {
    <li>
       {post}
    </li>
    }
    export default Post
```

**PostList.js**

```
class PostList extends React.Component {
componentDidMount() {
    console.log('did mount');
    this.props.fetchPosts();
}
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <ul>
                {this.state.posts(post => (
                    <Post key={post.id} {...post}  />
                ))}
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}
}

export default PostList
```

**Reducer**

```
export default (state = [], action) => {
switch (action.type) {
    case "FETCH_POSTS":
        return {
            ...state,
            loading: true,
            posts: []
        }
    case "FETCH_FAILD": 
        return {
            ...state,
            loading: false,
            posts: []
        }
    case "FETCH_SUCCESS":
        return Object.assign({}, state, {
            posts: action.posts
        })
    default:
        return state;
}
}
```

**Actions.js**

```
export const fetchPosts = () => {
  return {
    type: 'FETCH_POSTS'
  }
}

export const fetchSuccess = data => ({
    type: "FETCH_SUCCESS",
    posts: data
})


export const fetchFaild = () => {
    return {
        type: 'FETCH_FAILD'
    }
}
```

**GetPosts.js (Container)**

```
import  { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'

import PostList from '../components/PostList'

import { fetchPosts } from '../actions'

const mapStateToProps = state => ({ posts: state.posts });

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => bindActionCreators({fetchPosts}, dispatch);

const GetPosts = connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps 
)(PostList)

export default GetPosts
```

**Saga.js**

```
export function* fetchProducts() {
try {
    console.log('saga')
    const posts = yield call(api_fetchPost);
    yield put({ type: "FETCH_SUCCESS", posts});
} catch (e) {
    yield put({ type: "FETCH_FAILD", e});
    return;
}
}

export function* watchFetchProducts() {
    yield takeEvery("FETCH_POSTS", fetchProducts)
}
```

Comment: what is your problem exactly?

Comment: PostList.js:28 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'posts' of null
    at PostList.render (PostList.js:28)

Comment: ok, can you give me some example? Which is your way to solve this problem?

Comment: I think the problem is your initial state. It should be an object with posts set to empty array. Instead the initial state itself is empty array.

Comment: yes, you were right. tnx

Answer (score 0):

You are fetching posts from the state of your postlist component. Redux mapStateToProps map the redux state to connected component's props and not state

```
class PostList extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        console.log('did mount');
        this.props.fetchPosts();
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <ul>
                    {this.props.posts && this.props.posts.map(post => {
                        return ( <Post key={post.id} {...post}  /> );
                    })}
                </ul>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default PostList
```

Change `this.state.posts` to `this.props.posts`

Comment: i changed but i still have error,I add this for contructor and changed this.props.posts, but now error is this.props.posts is not a function                                   
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
     }

Comment: it shoud be this.props.posts.map and post should be an array. I am editing the answer

Comment: try adding a validation this.props.posts && this,props.posts.map()

Comment: i solved problem, it was in initial state and things you told. tnx